# Science/Evidence based guidelines on number of character for alert messages?

Tags: interface, alerts

I'm designing a design system  for multiple web-based app to manage customer license and account. I'm trying to set a character limit for these messages.

The company has culture of being verbose, and I'm having a hard time trying to convince on reducing text on alerts. Using the argument of being clean like Apple / Google guidelines, mobile first, doesn't work. I need to dig deeper and find something more rational like backed by academia or experts in the field.

Alerts would be things like this: https://mailchimp.com/help/about-error-messages/

Is there any study on the maximum length of characters for error or warning messages for an app?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am almost positive that there is no such research that resulted in a recommended specific number of characters to error/warning/alert messages. However, you **first** can investigate other researches that could support the idea of reducing text and amount of reading. [NNG](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/) research -quoted below- resulted in a law that users generally do not read Computer Documentations and shy away from doing any extra reading that is not essential to a task in hand.

> "Finally, you probably already know Nielsen's First Law of Computer Documentation: people don't read it. This finding is even stronger for websites, where users truly shy away from any reading that is not essential to their task. Click on Help? Never."

**Second**, you can use common sense that is supported by **facts**. More text means more reading which requires more **time!** Take Form Design as an example. In order to achieve an increase in the form completion rate, designers struggle to reduce the completion time (**Time!**).

Have in mind following the guidelines while trying to reduce the text! ([Here](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/)) NNG Error Messaging Guidelines.

One **main** guideline tells you to not just point out the error but also tell the user what to do. If we take this example:

**e.g.** *"This name is already taken. Please enter another name"*.

If I were to reduce the text here while having in mind that I still need to state the error and tell the user what to do next. I will maybe suggest this form:

*"Please enter a name that isn't already taken"*.

Hope that helps!